# How to do GROUP BY [empty]

Tags: sql, postgresql

Is there a way for **explicitly specifying an empty aggregation**, such as the following:

```
SELECT NULL AS Product, SUM(Revenue) FROM Sales GROUP BY ()
```

Rather than the implicit version which doesn't have a `GROUP BY` clause:

```
SELECT NULL AS Product, SUM(Revenue) FROM Sales
```

Sample input/output:

```
WITH Sales (Product, Revenue) AS (VALUES ('a',10),('b',20))
select NULL Product, SUM(Revenue) from Sales;
┌─────────┬──────────────┐
│ product ┆ sum(revenue) │
╞═════════╪══════════════╡
│         ┆           30 │
└─────────┴──────────────┘
```

The query is correct as-is, I'm just wondering if there is a way to make the `GROUP BY` explicit. This is for a very basic downstream parser that checks if it is an aggregation query based on if the words `GROUP BY` are in the normalized query.

Comment: I can't figure out what you are trying to achieve here.  Can you add sample data to explain?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen just to do a group by to get one output row.

Comment: Also, are you asking about Postgres or BigQuery?  They are not the same thing.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen let's say postgres.

Comment: Postgres already supports `ROLLUP`.  What is your question?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen How to do `SELECT Product, SUM(Revenue) GROUP BY ()`. I was just using ROLLUP to demonstrate.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen updated question.

Comment: Read about using `ROLLUP` with Postgres...that seems to be the functionality you want here.  There is no `GROUP BY ()` syntax in SQL AFAIK.

Comment: this question could benefit from some sample data and expected output

Comment: @HaleemurAli updated.

Comment: Would the parser detect the GROUP BY syntax if it was greened out? "--GROUP BY( )"?

Comment: @CliffordPiehl yea it's a 'normalized' query with some things parsed out and all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use expressions to group by. so grouping by an expression that is constant is equivalent removing it from the group by statement

i.e. the following are equivalent:

```sql
WITH Sales (Product, Revenue) AS (VALUES ('a',10),('b',20))
select NULL Product, SUM(Revenue) from Sales;
```

and

```sql
WITH Sales (Product, Revenue) AS (VALUES ('a',10),('b',20))
select NULL Product, SUM(Revenue) from Sales group by 1=1;
```

Comment: oh cool, in that case I can just add quotes around the `()`, so I have...`GROUP BY '()'` which would be a truthy-value.

Comment: @David542, `group by '()'` does not work as `'()'` is a string constant, and Postgresql does not allow grouping by string constants. you could do `group by '()'='()'`, or `group by (1=1)` if your downstream parser needs to consume the parentheses